# crc ip hdr checksum in verilog

Tags: networking, verilog, ipv4

I am implementing a task that i can use to obtain checksum from modified ip hdr. This is what i got:

```
task checksum_calc;
input [159:0] IP_hdr_data;
output [15:0] IP_chksum;
reg [19:0] IP_chksum_temp;
reg [19:0] IP_chksum_temp1;
reg [19:0] IP_chksum_temp2;
begin
  IP_chksum_temp = IP_hdr_data[15:0] + IP_hdr_data[31:16] + IP_hdr_data[47:32] + IP_hdr_data[63:48] + IP_hdr_data[79:64]  + IP_hdr_data[111:96]  + IP_hdr_data[127:112]  + IP_hdr_data[143:128]  + IP_hdr_data[159:144];
  IP_chksum_temp1 = IP_chksum_temp[15:0] + IP_chksum_temp[19:16];
  IP_chksum_temp2 = IP_chksum_temp1[15:0] + IP_chksum_temp1[19:16];
  IP_chksum = ! IP_chksum_temp2[15:0];
end
endtask
```

It's that correct? Or it will be some timing problems due to using cominational logic?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you are doing is some combination logic calculation. A functions is a better choice. The primary purpose of a function is to return a value that is to be used in an expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is huge combo logic, which in most of the scenario's will cause trouble for timing.
Better to run it through synthesis and timings check to know the exact result.

One suggestion as

```
IP_chksum_temp1 = IP_chksum_temp[15:0] + IP_chksum_temp[19:16];
```

can only generate flip the 16th bit. Hence, there is no need of 20 bits in next addition.

```
IP_chksum_temp2 = IP_chksum_temp1[15:0] + IP_chksum_temp1[19:16];
```

This can be done :-

```
reg [16:0] IP_chksum_temp1;
reg [16:0] IP_chksum_temp2;
```